# Get string from Parse.com iOS 8 Today Widget

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, widget, ios8-extension

I would like to retrieve a string from Parse.com in my notification centre widget. I have this code `Parse.setApplicationId("appId", clientKey: "clientKey")` in the widget's `viewDidLoad` but there is an error.
The error says:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'Parse'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added Parse and all needed frameworks to the widget target.  You may have added them to your apps target when you dragged them in but they need to be added to the widgets target as well if you plan on using them in there,

Comment: I have added the frameworks and I am still seeing the same error. Do I need to create a bridging header fro the extension too?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a bridging header for the extension as well as the app. Also you need to call Parse.setApplicationId() when your extension is loaded just as you do when your app is launched.